# Mongo DB compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The situation:
I have mongo db collection with user info. Among other fields it contains some user_email and user_login. These fields should be unique.
During registration i want to check the uniqueness. I'm doing it by

```
db.users.find( { $or: [ { user_email: email }, { user_name: name } ] } )
```

If i will find something, I can assume that data is not unique.

So the problem here is that users table can be huge and i decided to create compound index, based on these two fields. Mongo docs says:

> When using indexes with $or queries, each clause of an $or can use its
> own index. Consider the following query:
>
> db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ]
> } )
>
> To support this query, rather than a compound index, you would
> create one index on quantity and another index on price:
>
> db.inventory.createIndex( { quantity: 1 } )
>
> db.inventory.createIndex( { price: 1 } )
>
> MongoDB can use all but the geoHaystack index to
> support $or clauses.

So now I have 3 options:

- compound index
- two indexes
- geoHaysatck index ( read about it a bit, seems that it can search for "closest" index entry. Not sure this is the way that I should use )

Could you guys give me some hints on index picking for this particular use case?

Comment: If you don't know what it is then you simply do not use it. I think the documentation is pretty clear on what works best, don't you? I mean you actually included the very part that confirms what to do in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use two separate indexes. If you create a compound index, it will be useful for at most one of the two $or options.

With your $or query, the two parts will act much like separate queries:

1. `db.users.find( { user_email: email } )`
2. `db.users.find( { user_name: name } )`

If you create a compound index, say on user_email then user_name, then the first query will be able to make effective use of this - but the second query will not. The only way to optimise both parts of the query is to have separate indexes, one on each field.